# Is it possible to create directory without root permission in linux/unix?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

My parent working directory is /cam/local/edence/empus

By the above pwd the following directories are stored:

```
drwxr-xr-x 12 n i_ad 4096 Oct 31  2014 14.15
dr-xr-xr-x 12 n i_ad 4096 Feb 13  2015 14.22-s053
dr-xr-xr-x 12 n i_ad 4096 Sep  9  2015 15.12-s063
dr-xr-xr-x 12 n i_ad 4096 Mar 15  2016 15.21
```

My query is: Is it possible to create a new directory named(16.26) under the present working directory without root permission.I tried the command(mkdir 16.26) but it fails?

My Error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘16.26’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of permissions that are set for `/cam/local/edence/empus`.

Right now you don't seem to have write permissions for that directory.

Going by the example of `dr-xr-xr-x` you can see it's a directory and the owner, a group and everyone else has the permissions to read and execute. In order to create sub directories you'd have to have the write permission. You can use `chmod` to grant it and alternative would be to take ownership `chown` or add yourself to the group for that directory by using `usermod -aG <group> <user>` and grating write permissions for that group.

Comment: suppose,if am the user mech is it right way to use the command like usermod -aG i_ad mech @ Seth

Comment: It should be but make sure that `empus` is actually assigned to that group. So you need to check the permissions in `/cam/local/edence` as well.

Comment: Permission for /cam/local/edence

lrwxrwxrwx  1 n i_ad    6 Jun 10 10:44 viltus -> empus

@Seth

Comment: Should be fine than.

Comment: Hai, I treid in the following manner:                                                   usermod -g -G empus,mech empus but still i receives the error "/usr/sbin/usermod permission denied"

Comment: Well in order to add someone to a group you need to have administrative privileges. On most modern systems there is `sudo` setup for such tasks (if you actually do have sufficient access for that system). So the command would be `sudo usermod -aG i_ad mech`. Be very careful with usermod(!) your above example has the wrong order of arguments and even if it was right would change the primary group of the user and remove him from any optional groups except one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45619/discussion-between-sago-and-seth).

Answer (score 0):

```
newgrp command works fine for above query
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.